# Wrapping C++ functions with GNU linker

Tags: c++, linker, mocking

I like the GNU linker functionality to wrap functions a lot. I normally use it mock e.g. nondeterministic function calls like `rand()`. Consider the following example where I would like to write a unit test for `giveMeANumber`:

```
//number.cpp
int giveMeANumber() {
  return rand() % 6 + 1;
}
```

I can wrap the call to rand with the GNU linker functionality wrap like this:

```
//test.cpp
extern "C" int __wrap_rand(void) {
return 4;
}

void unitTest() {
  assert giveMeANumber() == 5;
}

$ g++ test.cpp -o test number.o -Xlinker --wrap=rand
```

Is there any way to do the same with normal C++ functions? The following does not work, I guess it is because of name mangling. But even when I try it with the mangled name it does not work.

```
//number.cpp
int foo() {
  //some complex calculations I would like to mock
}
int giveMeANumber() {
  return foo() % 6 + 1;
}

//test.cpp
extern "C" int __wrap_foo(void) {
return 4;
}

$ g++ test.cpp -o test number.o -Xlinker --wrap=foo
```

Comment: Actually, rand is a deterministic function.  It returns a pseudo-random number sequence.  Calls the rand will return the same sequence of numbers for any given seed used with srand.

Comment: Okay, bravo, that's true. But to keep the example short and readable, I didn't use a seed.

Comment: You need to rename `__wrap_foo` to `getRandomNumber`. (http://xkcd.com/221/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to either also `extern "C"` the function you want to wrap (if that's possible) or you need to wrap the mangled name, e.g., `__wrap__Z3foov` and then pass `--wrap=_Z3foov` to the linker.

Getting the underscores right is a little tricky. This works for me:

```
$ cat x.cc
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int giveMeANumber();

int main() {
    cerr << giveMeANumber() << endl;
    return 0;
}

$ cat y.cc
int giveMeANumber() {
    return 0;
}

extern "C" int __wrap__Z13giveMeANumberv() {
    return 10;
}

$ g++ -c x.cc y.cc && g++ x.o y.o -Wl,--wrap=_Z13giveMeANumberv && ./a.out
10
```

Comment: C linkage for the to be wrapped C++ function is not an option because this function could be overloaded and it should still be possible to call it from other C++ functions. I tried to wrap the mangled name, but it does not work. What I did is this: `extern "C" int __wrap__Z3foov(void) {
 return 4;
}
void thisIsATest() {
  assert 5 == giveMeANumber();
}
` together with the linker option `-Xlinker --wrap=_Z3foov`. Unfortunately, the real `foo` function is still being called. Any ideas?

Comment: I added an example. Took me a while to get all the underscores right.

Comment: And thanks for the question. I didn't even know about --wrap. Very nice.

Comment: if we change the name of function "giveMeANumber" it call the real function and note the _wrap__Z13....v are their a relation between the name of function and the prefix ??

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to mock functions and classes for testing. Have you consider using **[Google Mock](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/ForDummies)**

Comment: Using Google mock is not an option for me. I want to accomplish this solely with the help of the GNU linker.

Comment: Google Mock relies on virtual methods. The wrap option is extremely useful for mocking non-virtual methods.