# Is there any way to declare function as extern "C" with g++ flag?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I am referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402491/wrapping-c-functions-with-gnu-linker) thread, I have the same requirement (wrap the function call) which requires the extern "C" declaration.

In my case this prototype is declared under a separate header file, I don't want to change this header file or the original code file (in which function call is made).
But still I want the compiler to see my function as extern "C".
So, I am wondering if there is a way to provide this information with g++ flag (e.g. something like "--externc=foobar").

Comment: It would help us if you really gave the declaration code of the actual function you want to modify in the question.

Answer (score 4):

When including C headers you usually need to wrap them with an `extern "C"` block if they don't have the corresponding wrapper [conditionally on `__cplusplus`] inside:

```
extern "C" {
#include <c-header.h>
}
```

Nesting these blocks is harmless except that it prevents the header to be migrated to C++, i.e., the internal `extern "C"`-block is preferrable. If the header is a C++ header you'll need to jump theough a forwarding function:

```
extern "C" void call_as_c() {
    actual_cxx_function();
}
```

Sinply pretending that the linkage of a symbol is different than it actually is doesn't quite work.

Comment: But this might not work if the header is truly C++, e.g. if it contains overloaded functions of same name but different signatures.

Comment: The second solution (inline function) should work, I think. But since the OP does **not** want to change the call site, you would also need a macro to turn the `actual_function` call in the source to `call_as_c` (which ironically then calls `actual_function`).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: correct. Hence the comment on what to do if the header happens to be a C++ header at the bottom if my answer.

Comment: @ Damon: OK, I missed that. Well, I want many things I can't have. Unless there is a technical reason for these desires, I'd think the proper solution is to deal with it. Any macro hackery which could be used is as fragile as renaming symbols.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the linkage / calling convention (which is what `extern "C"` has every right to do), pretty much the only safe answer is to change it where the function is declared -- ie: in the header.  Otherwise, you risk the function being defined differently than it's used, and hilarity ensues.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not easily possible (to post-declare as `extern "C"` exactly one function declared in some previous header).

If you have only one such function (and not many of them), I think the easiest solution would be to either change the header, or perhaps declare that function `extern "C"` before including the header (if the signature and the arguments or result types of that function permit it, e.g. if the relevant types are defined in some other header, etc...).

Alternatively, write some (e.g. in `sed` or `awk`) script which would transform the header.

You could also consider customizing GCC with e.g. an extension coded in [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (a domain specific language to extend GCC) which would change the internal representation of your declaration as you like. I'm not sure it is worth the effort in your case.